# Get size of keyboard keys programmatically in iOS with Swift or Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, keyboard

I know I can get the size of the keyboard itself using the callback for `keyboardWasShown` in the `userInfo` dictionary. However what I need to know is the size of the actual keys on said keyboard. 
I would like to use this information to replicate extra keys above the keyboard. 
I do not want to make a custom keyboard because I do not want this keyboard to be used outside of this application. I just want a couple of extra keys above to be a shortcut to certain keys. 
Is there a way to find the size of the keys (which should be different for iPhone and iPad).

Comment: are you able to find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Add observer in ViewWillAppear Method

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
}
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note{
 CGRect keyboardBounds;
[[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

 // Need to translate the bounds to account for rotation.

keyboardBounds = [self.view convertRect:keyboardBounds toView:nil];
CGFloat keyboardHeight= keyboardBounds.size.height;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
   // unregister for keyboard notifications while not visible.
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                              object:nil];


 }
```

Comment: Does this get the keyboard height or the keyboard keys height? I am looking for the keyboard keys height.

Comment: Sorry Johnston ,this will be helpful for Keyboard Height only. If you found any for getting size of keys of keyboard then post please.

Comment: Thanks for your help but: Did you even read the first sentence of the post? "I know I can get the size of the keyboard itself using the callback for keyboardWasShown"